# Docker: Ship log files being written inside containers to ELK stack

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, docker-container

I am running a `django` application using `docker`, and using `python` logging in `django` settings to write api logs inside a logs folder. When I restart my container my log files are also removed (which is understandable).

I would like to ship my logs (e.g. `/path/to/workdir/logs/django.log`) to `elasticsearch`. I am confused since my searches tell me to ship this path `/var/lib/docker/containers/*/*.log`  but I don't think this is what I want.

Any ideas on how I ship my logs inside the container to ELK Stack?

Comment: `/path/to/workdir/logs/django.log` is the location inside of the container, `/var/lib/docker/containers/<container>/.log` refers to a location on the `docker` host (I'm not certain the path is relevant in the latest versions of `docker`) - posisbly outdated resources(?). I would output the `django` logs to `stdout` / `stderr`, configure the `docker` service with the [`gelf`](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/gelf/) logging driver, consume that with `logstash` using the [`gelf`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-gelf.html) plugin outputting to ES.

Comment: Make that an answer, its the correct one.

Comment: @PaulBecotte sure thing, as soon as I get some time I’ll post a functional example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can ship logs from `docker` containers `stdout` / `stderr` to `elasticsearch` using the [`gelf`](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/configure/#supported-logging-drivers) logging driver.

Configure the services to with the `gelf` logging driver (`docker-compose.yml`):

```
version: '3.7'
x-logging:
  &logstash
  options:
    gelf-address: "udp://localhost:12201"
  driver: gelf
services:
  nginx:
    image: 'nginx:1.17.3'
    hostname: 'nginx'
    domainname: 'example.com'
    depends_on:
    - 'logstash'
    ports:
    - '80:80'
    volumes:
    - '${PWD}/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro'
    logging: *logstash
  elasticsearch:
    image: 'elasticsearch:7.1.1'
    environment:
    - 'discovery.type=single-node'
    volumes:
    - 'elasticsearch:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data'
    expose:
    - '9200'
    - '9300'
  kibana:
    image: 'kibana:7.1.1'
    depends_on:
    - 'elasticsearch'
    ports:
    - '5601:5601'
    volumes:
    - '${PWD}/kibana/kibana.yml:/usr/share/kibana/config/kibana.yml'
  logstash:
    build: 'logstash'
    depends_on:
    - 'elasticsearch'
    volumes:
    - 'logstash:/usr/share/logstash/data'
    ports:
    - '12201:12201/udp'
    - '10514:10514/udp'
volumes:
  elasticsearch:
  logstash:
```

**Note**: the above example configures the logging using [extension fields](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#extension-fields).

The [minimal `nginx.conf`](https://serverfault.com/a/491817/526382) used for this example:

```
user nginx;
worker_processes 1;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log debug;

pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
  server {
    listen 80;
    server_name _;

    location / {
      return 200 'OK';
    }
  }
}
```

The `logstash` image is a custom build using the below `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM logstash:7.1.1

USER 0
COPY pipeline/gelf.cfg /usr/share/logstash/pipeline
COPY pipeline/pipelines.yml /usr/share/logstash/config
COPY settings/logstash.yml /usr/share/logstash/config
COPY patterns /usr/share/logstash/patterns

RUN rm /usr/share/logstash/pipeline/logstash.conf
RUN chown -R 1000:0 /usr/share/logstash/pipeline /usr/share/logstash/patterns /usr/share/logstash/config
USER 1000
```

... the relevant `logstash` [`gelf` plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-gelf.html) config:

```
input {
  gelf {
    type => docker
    port => 12201
  }
}

filter { }

output {
  if [type] == "docker" {
    elasticsearch { hosts => ["elasticsearch:9200"] }
    stdout { codec => rubydebug }
  }
}
```

... and `pipelines.yml`:

```
- pipeline.id: "gelf"
  path.config: "/usr/share/logstash/pipeline/gelf.cfg"
```

... and `logstash.yml` to persist the data:

```
queue:
  type: persisted
  drain: true
```

The process running in the container logs to `stdout` / `stderr`, `docker` pushes the logs to `logstash` using the `gelf` logging driver (**note**: the `logstash` address is `localhost` because the `docker` service discovery is not available to resolve the service name - the ports must be mapped to the host and the logging driver must be configured using `localhost`) which outputs the logs to `elasticsearch` that you can index in `kibana`:

[image]

Comment: What is the contents of the file `logstash/settings/logstash.yml` referenced in the custom logstash `Dockerfile`?