# Trouble with updating running VueJs app in production without downtime

Tags: docker, vue.js, nginx, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a problem updating running in production mode VueJS app. Every time instead of just running

`docker-compose up --build`

I should do

```
docker-compose down
docker volume rm mkstat_frontend_dist
docker-compose up --build
```

And there is a lot of downtime during this, so I want to solve this problem. I understanding that this is because of volume, but don't know how to solve this.
I've tried just remove this volume but then nginx responding with

`directory index of "/app/dist/" is forbidden`

This is my app structure:

```
.
├── docker/
├── docker-compose.back.yml
├── docker-compose.dev.yml
├── docker-compose.yml
├── fresh_dump.sql
├── init-letsencrypt.sh
├── mkstat_backend/
├── mkstat_frontend/
├── redis.conf
```

This is my prod docker-compose file:

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  backend:
    container_name: backend
    restart: always
    build:
      context: ./mkstat_backend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.prod
    volumes:
      - static:/app/static
      - media:/app/media
    env_file:
      - ./mkstat_backend/.env.prod
    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    container_name: db
    restart: always
    build:
      context: ./docker/postgres
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    env_file:
      - ./mkstat_backend/.env.prod

  frontend:
    container_name: frontend
    build:
      context: ./mkstat_frontend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.prod
    volumes:
      - frontend_dist:/app/dist
    depends_on:
      - backend

  nginx:
    image: nginx:alpine
    restart: unless-stopped
    command: '/bin/sh -c ''while :; do sleep 6h & wait $${!}; nginx -s reload; done & nginx -g "daemon off;"'''
    container_name: nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./docker/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      - ./docker/certbot/conf:/etc/letsencrypt
      - ./docker/certbot/www:/var/www/certbot
      - static:/var/html/static
      - media:/var/html/media
      - frontend_dist:/app/dist
    depends_on:
      - backend
      - frontend

  certbot:
    container_name: certbot
    image: certbot/certbot
    restart: unless-stopped
    entrypoint: "/bin/sh -c 'trap exit TERM; while :; do certbot renew; sleep 12h & wait $${!}; done;'"

    volumes:
      - ./docker/certbot/conf:/etc/letsencrypt
      - ./docker/certbot/www:/var/www/certbot

  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    restart: always
    container_name: redis

    command: [
        "bash",
        "-c",
        "
        redis-server
        --requirepass $${REDIS_PASS}
        ",
      ]
    volumes:
      - redis:/var/lib/redis/data
      - ./redis.conf:/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
    ports:
      - "6379"
    env_file:
      - ./mkstat_backend/.env.prod

  worker:
    build:
      context: ./mkstat_backend
    command: celery -A mkstat worker -B -l info -s /tmp/celerybeat-schedule
    restart: always
    container_name: celery
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis
      - backend
    volumes:
      - ./mkstat_backend:/app
    env_file:
      - ./mkstat_backend/.env.prod

volumes:
  pgdata:
  static:
  media:
  frontend_dist:
  redis:
```

Vue Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:lts-alpine as build
WORKDIR /app
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
COPY package.json /app/package.json
RUN npm install --silent
RUN npm install @vue/cli@4.5.13 -g
COPY . /app
RUN npm run build
```

Comment: i never managed to do it with docker only. but if you learn docker swarm it will work automatically because it provides a mecanism for rolling updates ( the new project will be started. healthcheckd, then the old one will be shut down => hence providing zero downtime). you can keep your actual docker compose file, add a deploy section for each service and provide it to docker swarm. Without docker swarm you would need to start a second docker-compose project and load balance between the first and the second accordingly.

Comment: You can `docker-compose build` before taking the project down, e.g. `docker-compose build && docker-compose down && docker volume rm mkstat_frontend_dist && docker-compose up -d`. Won't give you zero downtime but you don't have to build at the moment you're bringing the services back up, and building before dropping the services will prevent the services from being offline while the image is building.

Comment: @masseyb That might help. But most importantly I want to know, do I really need that volume? Or should I use image instead? And why in the official docs there is there nginx in the VueJS Dockerfile https://vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/dockerize-vuejs-app.html#Real-World-Example

Comment: @karambaq I wouldn't use a volume there, no, for production images I would only ever use the built image. Concerning the doc, they use nginx "for realistically complex production use cases". I would suggest nginx over apache any day, I also use it extensively (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/57741684/1423507), in their example it serves as a webserver to serve the built application (suggested for production), in the [second stage](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/) the built dist is copied into the nginx root location.

Comment: @masseyb Thanks. I will try to use an image. I didn't really found some good examples or best-practices with docker-compose in production.  
1. So the pipeline would be:
I'm pushing image on dockerhub, then pulling it on the server, building, and then down'ing current one and up'ing new?

2) About that nginx part, do I need to use it if my docker-compose already has nginx? 

3) Also would be very thankful if you can suggest some examples when it's used with docker-compose and image in production. 

Thank you already, you made a good point.

Comment: @karambaq (1) if you're pushing the images to [Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/) then you've already built them, your pipeline would be e.g.: build then push the image, pull the image on the host, down and up the services. (2) "need", no, you can serve the vue.js app however you want and configure your nginx service with an upstream for the frontend service. (3) using docker-compose in production, as a rule of thumb I would make sure [these points](https://docs.docker.com/compose/production/) are addressed (e.g. ELK logging https://stackoverflow.com/a/58556254/1423507).

Comment: @masseyb Thanks! Will try. If you can leave a full answer I will mark it as solved (don't sure if I can do that to comment).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## TL;DR

```shell
docker-compose down
docker volume rm mkstat_frontend_dist
docker-compose up --build
```

... is not optimal as the services will be down for the duration of the build. The services don't need to be taken down for the build, thus:

```shell
docker-compose build
docker-compose down
docker volume rm mststat_frontend_dist
docker-compose up -d
```

... would be slightly more efficient as the services would only be taken offline to purge the old containers and volume then new containers will be created from the pre-built images.

---

The volume backing the `dist` files isn't needed as far as I can tell, you could remove it. The `dist` files served in the deployment would be that which is built in the image without having to drop the volume every re-deployment.

If you're pushing your images to [Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/) or other docker registry then the image(s) have already been built, you don't need to re-build during the re-deployment. Your process might look like:

- build the docker image on your PC
- push the docker image to the docker registry
- pull the docker image on the server
- `docker-compose down` the services to remove the old containers
- `docker-compose up -d` to start new containers from the images

For a production deployment of nginx, this is the example config that I use as a base:

```tcl
worker_processes 1;

error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
  worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
  map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
    default upgrade;
    '' close;
  }

  include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  default_type application/octet-stream;

  log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                    '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                    '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

  client_max_body_size 0;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log main;
  sendfile on;
  keepalive_timeout 65;

  upstream web {
    server web:80 max_fails=3;
  }
  server {
    listen *:80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name _;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
  }
  add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;
  add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
  add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains; preload";
  add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self';";
  server {
    listen *:443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name *.example.com example.com;
    charset utf-8;

    error_page 404 = @notfound;

    server_tokens off;

    proxy_buffer_size 128k;
    proxy_buffers 4 256k;
    proxy_busy_buffers_size 256k;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
    ssl_session_timeout 1d;
    ssl_session_tickets off;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/ssl/dhparam.pem;

    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!DSS';

    resolver 127.0.0.11 1.1.1.1 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 valid=86400s;
    resolver_timeout 5s;
    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;
    ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/chain.pem;

    error_page 404 = @notfound;

    location @notfound {
      return 301 /;
    }
    location /healthz {
      allow 127.0.0.1;
      deny all;
      stub_status;
    }
    location / {
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header HOST $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_pass http://web/;
    }
  }
}
```

> The `nginx.conf` example is the result of a few third-party pentests, e.g. `server_tokens` ([Default: on](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#server_tokens)) will be flagged, allowing old versions of TLS/SSL will be flagged, not setting the `Content-Security-Policy` header will be flagged, etc.