# Gelf logging with docker-compose

Tags: docker, graylog, gelf

I've googled the f out of this.

here is the log driver config for my docker container in the compose file

```
       driver: gelf
       options:
          gelf-address: "http://graylog:12201"
```

I created a GELF HTTP input in the admin console.
I know that graylog is accessible at 12201, because if I ssh into a container and run

`curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{ "version": "1.1", "host": "example.org", "short_message": "A short message", "level": 5, "_some_info": "test" }' 'http://graylog:12201/gelf'`

Then I can see the log message.

The problem is, it seems like I have to add the `/gelf` to the address, but docker complains if I try to do that. But no other curl commands work without it, and I can't seem to get it to work with TCP or UDP at all. So.... what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Docker: Ship log files being written inside containers to ELK stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58545087/docker-ship-log-files-being-written-inside-containers-to-elk-stack)